# fadeOut an element after it has been shown for some time

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to have the `.status-bar` appear %100 for a set time interval and then start to fade away when the time interval expires. The problem I am having is, right now as soon as the code below executes the status bar appears and starts fading away instantly (please note that the code below is part of a bigger click function).

I was wondering if someone can help me identify what I need to do to accomplish this.

```
setTimeout(function(){
     $(".status-bar").show();
     $(".status-bar").fadeOut(5000, function () {

    });
}, 0);
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use setTimeout. Insead of that use [**delay()**](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

```
$('.status-bar"').delay(2000).fadeOut();
```